# Scripting in php variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

I am trying to throw in a html comment box, in one of the outputs that I echo out on the site, but nothing comes up when I try.

```
$output .= "<div id=\"HCB_comment_box\"><a href=\"http://www.htmlcommentbox.com\">HTML Comment Box</a> is loading comments...</div>";


$output .=" <script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" id=\"hcb\"> if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={  };} (function(){s==document.createElement(\"script\");s.setAttribute(\"type\",\"text/javascript\");s.setAttribute(\"src\", \"http://www.htmlcommentbox.com/jread?page=\"+escape((window.hcb_user && hcb_user.PAGE)||(\"\"+window.location)).replace(\"+\",\"%2B\")+\"&opts=470&num=10\");if (typeof s!=\"undefined\") document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(s);})();  </script>";
```

The thing is, that the first output comes out fine, but the second one, with the real content in it - doesn't.

Help me please.

---

ANSWERED!

I found out the answer on my own.

Before

{s==document.createElement(\"script\");

Apparently == destroys the script, so it should be

{s=document.createElement(\"script\"); not sure why, but it worked.

Now I just need to figure out how to style it, but I'll figure that out on my own! Thank you all for the quick responses!

Comment: "doesn't come out fine"? What does that mean? Show us the HTML it produces.

Comment: is there an `echo $output;` anywhere? Which is the "first" output...both lines are part of the same variable.

Comment: PHP is meant to handle HTML natively - write raw HTML, and enter PHP w/ `<?php ?>` tags when needed, don't wreck your life by escaping quotes!

Comment: The second output is just a <script/> tag are you sure that the source that it is referencing is correct? Open up developer tools in your browser and see what the source is that it is calling and if it is correct.

Comment: Let me see, I'm on the train ATM. So don't have my laptop, but I'll try to aswer your questions. The HTML echoes "HTML comment bow is loading..." And under that - nothing. There is an echo $output; else nothing would show up. The output first line is $output ='' "; - I will check the dev tool when I come home! Thank you all for the quick responses :-)

Comment: I found out the answer on my own.

Before

{s==document.createElement(\"script\");

Apparently == destroys the script, so it should be

{s=document.createElement(\"script\"); not sure why, but it worked.

Now I just need to figure out how to style it, but I'll figure that out on my own! Thank you all for the quick responses.

The reason that I post this in comments is, That i Can't answer my own question yet. so if somebody post that, it'll be the answer!

Answer (score -1):

before

`$output .= "<div id=\"HCB_comment_box\"><a href=\"http://www.htmlcommentbox.com\">HTML Comment Box</a> is loading comments...</div>";`

begin that var with null, like this

```
$output = null;
```

Comment: And what will setting `$output` to null accomplish? If your going to initialize the variable better cast it as a string and not null (eg. `$output = '';`).

Comment: @user555 both option are correct, because PHP it's a adaptive language, the system will transform $output in a string.